# Erro: SQL Server String or binary data would be truncated

Tags: sql, banco-de-dados, sql-server

Tenho a variável `@numero1` que traz o seguinte resultado:

> 020000000000720000018

Mas na hora do update dá o erro:

> SQL Server String or binary data would be truncated

```
declare @g1 varchar(50)
declare @numero1 varchar(50)
set @g1 = SUBSTRING(@vNossoNumero, 1, 2) + REPLICATE('0', 9) + 
SUBSTRING(@vNossoNumero, 3, LEN(@vNossoNumero))
set @numero1 = left(@g1,Max(LEN(@g1))-2)

print @numero1 // - dá erro nessa variável

update DUPLICATA set DupNossoNumBco=@numero1 where DupNum=(  
select ParcDocFinDupNum from PARC_DOC_FIN   
where EMPCOD      = @EMPCOD  
AND  DOCFINCHV     = @DOCFINCHV  
AND  PARCDOCFINSEQ    = @PARCDOCFINSEQ  
AND  PARCDOCFINDESMPAG   = @PARCDOCFINDESMPAG  
)  

END
```

Comment: Esse erro está relacionado com o tamanho do `varchar` que vai receber o update. Pode colocar na pergunta o tamanho do campo `DupNossoNumBco`?

Comment: Ele possui o tamanho 20

Comment: Então você já achou a resposta. A sua variável tem um conteúdo de 21 caracteres. =)

Comment: Tem algo de estranho/curioso é no uso de max()

Comment: O resultado da variável `@numero1` acaba por ser 28, por isso, tentando atualizar um campo de tamanho 20 com 28 caracteres dá erro.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O problema está no facto do seu campo `DupNossoNumBco` ter apenas tamanho **20** (segundo a informação que disponibilizou em comentário) e a variável `@numero1` chegar aos **28** caracteres:

```
-- @vNossoNumero = '020000000000720000018'
DECLARE @g1         VARCHAR(50)
DECLARE @numero1    VARCHAR(50)

SET @g1         = SUBSTRING(@vNossoNumero, 1, 2) + REPLICATE('0', 9) + SUBSTRING(@vNossoNumero, 3, LEN(@vNossoNumero))
SET @numero1    = LEFT(@g1, MAX(LEN(@g1)) - 2)

PRINT LEN(@numero1)
-- imprime "28"
```

Para isto tem duas soluções, ou aumenta o tamanho do campo para aquele que mais se adequa, sendo o suficiente para suportar a variável `@numero1`, ou, caso não possa mesmo alterar o tamanho, faz um `SUBSTRING` no momento em que for fazer o `UPDATE`:

```
SET DupNossoNumBco = SUBSTRING(@numero1, 1, 20)
```